# Adding Activities to an existing Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I wanted to know if it is possible to Add Queries and imports to an existing Automation.  Can I edit the Automation and add my activities when the Automation is not running or do I need to copy the Automation and add the new activities?

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pause the automation and then you can make the required changes. After you are finished, you will just activate the automation again and it will run using the new activities you put in.